# Show radio Property in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this radio button that I click and it does click. Except when I inspect the DOM I do not see the checked attribute being added, but I can see that the property check has been set to true. I need to be able to preserve this state since I am saving the HTML. Is there away to add/remove the checked attribute as the property changes? Other than adding a handler on click and checking the property to add or remove the attribute.

[image]

Comment: You'd have to manually add it.

Comment: @tymeJV I was trying to avoid that but I guess I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to manually set that if you want the DOM to change. The DOM does not automatically modifies itself.

To get the current value of the radio button use javascript:

```
document.getElementById("radio_group_92").checked // true or false
```

To set the value, use this:

```
var radiobtn = document.getElementById("the_id_of_the_group");
radiobtn.checked = true;
```

The radio button [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp) only specifies about the checked property:

> **Definition and Usage**
>
> The checked property sets or returns the checked state of a radio
>   button.
>
> This property reflects the HTML checked attribute.

Comment: thnx I was hoping for a simplier way but I will accept that,.

Comment: @jackthor I personally find JQuery to be simpler than javascript, but that's me.

Comment: with JQuery `$('input[name=foo]').attr('checked', true);`

Comment: You could use JS to automatically toggle the `checked` attribute on click.

Answer (score 0):

There are properties and attributes. Attributes are part of the XHTML and properties are not. In general, setting the property does not affect the attribute on the DOM like in your example or the value attribute of a text input. There are some exceptions though, like the id and name properties which will change the attributes of the DOM too. 
In your case you will indeed have to manually check for the checked property as @cacho suggested. However, I think that the change event is more suitable than the click.

```
 document.getElementById("radio_group_92").addEventListener("change", function(e){ 
     console.log(e.target.checked);
 }, false);
```